# Elements rotated on the Y-axis bisect fixed containers

Tags: css, safari, transform

This appears to effect **only Safari browsers**, but all versions I have tested on.

For some reason when rotating an element on the Y-axis, when it is positioned on top of a fixed container, the element cuts through it. Like this;

[image: rotated SO logo]

```
.fixed-container {
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 0;
  background: skyblue;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 400px;
}

.transformed-element {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: contain;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateZ(-64deg) rotateX(10deg) rotateY(50deg);
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateZ(-64deg) rotateX(17deg) rotateY(50deg);
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  background: url(http://scalabilitysolved.com/content/images/2014/May/stackoverflow.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

[Here is the jsfiddle of the above code.](http://jsfiddle.net/6pqMu/12/)

Is this intended behaviour or a browser bug? How can I achieve what I want on top a fixed container?